# Dajax Hello World

Tags: python, django, dajaxice, dajax

I can't seem to get a simple hello world response from Dajax, after all day of working on hello world. (I'm sure you'll realize that this is word for word from the hello world guide)

I have an apps folder Example: proj/apps/myapp

I have created ajax.py inside of myapp:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register
def sayhello(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Hello World'})
```

I have my template:

```
{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}

<html>
  <head>
    <title>My base template</title>
    ...
    {% dajaxice_js_import %}
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function my_js_callback(data){
      alert(data.message);
    }
  </script>
    <input type="button" onclick="Dajaxice.myapp.sayhello(my_js_callback);" value="test">
</html>
```

This doesn't work. I have also followed the installation guide word for word found: http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I'm losing my mind.

Comment: Are you properly serving the dajax static files? I believe `dajaxice_js_import` automatically checks if your static urls are correctly configured, but it can't hurt to verify it manually. Check your web console to see if its loading the dajaxice js properly.

Comment: @RomanAlexander Yep, I have it setup in the URLs to serve the files and I can see from runserver that it's pulling the static files appropriately.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I forgot a closing bracket. Thanks @RomanAlexander for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

A closing bracket was omitted in the OPs original efforts.